# Automate volume snapshots on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I found this excellent service https://app.cloudzy.io/ to backup/create snapshots for my AWS instances on a schedule and being able to set the retention. Very simple and easy to use

I just got an email from them that they are shutting down the service.

Now I'm looking for something similar that is affordable. Any recommendations?

Comment: I do not know your exact requirements, but I would checkout Skeddly. https://www.skeddly.com/  I use them and like it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search found exactly what you needed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html

Comment: Not even close to what https://app.cloudzy.io/ does. No way to set retentions and using tags among other things

Answer (score 0):

It’s fairly easy to roll your own with a scheduled Lambda function.  I wrote a script similar to the one here: https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/

If you are willing to spend money, N2WS is your next best bet. https://n2ws.com/